# Easiest way to make this stamp 4 by 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

(Sorry, still pretty new to Python) 
Here's my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen


coordinate_calc = 20  ## Will be used later to calculate equal coordinates
                      ## for the turtles.

def pattern_printer1(turtle, start, stop, step):
    '''Calculates coordinates and sends turtles to them, and stamps in
a tessellating pattern.'''
    for x in range(start, stop + 1, step):
        for y in range(start, stop + 1, step):
            turtle.goto(x * coordinate_calc, y * coordinate_calc)
            turtle.stamp()

def square_perameters1(big_color, small_color, size):
    '''Constructs two separate turtles to create the large star shape,
and the small. Takes two color and one size parameters.'''
    alex = Turtle(shape="square") ## Creates the first turtle in the shape of a square.
    alex.shapesize(size)
    alex.color(big_color)
    alex.penup()


    pattern_printer1(alex, -12, 12, 12) ## Calls pattern printing function.

    tess = Turtle(shape="square") ## Creates the second turtle in the shape of a square.
    tess.shapesize(size/2) ## To fit the pattern, the second star shape will be
                           ## one half of the size of the first.
    tess.color(small_color)
    tess.penup()

    pattern_printer1(tess, -6, 6, 12) ## Calls pattern printing function.

def pattern_printer2(turtle, start, stop, step):
    '''Calculates coordinates and sends turtles to them, and stamps in
a tessellating pattern.'''
    turtle.lt(45)
    for x in range(start, stop + 1, step):
        for y in range(start, stop + 1, step):
            turtle.goto(x * coordinate_calc, y * coordinate_calc)
            turtle.stamp()

def square_perameters2(big_color, small_color, size):
    '''Constructs two separate turtles to create the large star shape,
and the small. Takes two color and one size parameters.'''

    alex = Turtle(shape="square") ## Creates the first turtle in the shape of a square.
    alex.shapesize(size + .5)
    alex.color(big_color)
    alex.penup()


    pattern_printer2(alex, -12, 12, 12) ## Calls pattern printing function.

    tess = Turtle(shape="square") ## Creates the second turtle in the shape of a square.
    tess.shapesize((size + .5)/2) ## To fit the pattern, the second star shape will be
                                  ## one half of the size of the first.
    tess.color(small_color)
    tess.penup()

    pattern_printer2(tess, -6, 6, 12) ## Calls pattern printing function.

square_perameters1("dark red", "orange", 8)
square_perameters2("dark red", "orange", 8)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick() ## If the window is clicked after the turtles have finished
                     ## drawing, the window will close.
```

I'd like this pattern to be 4 by 4, rather than 3 by 3, if possible. I tried to add another argument to the range, but of course, it only accepts three. So, will I have to rework a larger portion of this code? Or can I simply add another row?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! The problem you have is in your calls to `pattern_printer1` and `pattern_printer2`. The arguments to the `pattern_printer` functions are `turtle, start, stop, step`. The `turtle` bit is obvious, but let's talk about the other three. In Python, ranges exclude the last element. So, `list(range(10, 15)) == [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`. That's true even when you're using a step.

You call the `pattern_printer1(alex, -12, 12, 12)`, and `pattern_printer1` creates a `range(start, stop + 1, step)`. If we plug in the values from the function call, we can see that the range being created is `range(-12, 12 + 1, 12)`.

Now, based on what we know about Python's ranges, we can figure out what values are going to be in the range: `[-12, 0, 12]`. If you had written `range(start, stop, step)` instead of `range(start, stop + 1, step)`, the `12` wouldn't be included.

Anyhow, you want to add a fourth row and column to your drawing. To do that, we need to make sure that there are four items in our range! We can either increase the bounds of the range, or decrease the step.

In this case, increasing the size of the range - for example, calling `pattern_printer1(alex, -24, 12, 12)` - would create the right sized range, but would result in parts being drawn off-screen.

As a result, our best option is to decrease the  size from 12 to 8, because 8 also divides 24 evenly. Sure enough, if you change the function call to `pattern_printer1(alex, -12, 12, 8)`, you'll see a very nice 4x4 grid.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have taken the [solution I provided earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005952/simpler-way-to-make-a-square-and-rotated-square-in-python-turtle-graphics) and made it as complicated as possible.  Let's go back to the original, simpler solution and make it so it can be adjusted as desired:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

PATTERN_WIDTH = 4
BIG_COLOR = "dark red"
SMALL_COLOR = "orange"

def print_pattern(turtle, start, stop, size, offset=0):
    for x in range(start, stop + 1):
        for y in range(start, stop + 1):
            turtle.goto(x * STAMP_WIDTH * size + offset, y * STAMP_WIDTH * size + offset)
            turtle.stamp()

def configure_turtle(size, color):
    turtle = Turtle(shape="star")
    turtle.shapesize(size)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.speed("fastest")
    turtle.penup()

    return turtle

STAMP_WIDTH = 6

star = ( \
    ( 3,  0), ( 2, -1), ( 2, -2), ( 1, -2), \
    ( 0, -3), (-1, -2), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), \
    (-3,  0), (-2,  1), (-2,  2), (-1,  2), \
    ( 0,  3), ( 1,  2), ( 2,  2), ( 2,  1), \
 )

screen = Screen()

screen.register_shape("star", star)

screen_width = (screen.window_width() // STAMP_WIDTH)

star_size = int(screen_width / PATTERN_WIDTH)

alex = configure_turtle(star_size, BIG_COLOR)

print_pattern(alex, -PATTERN_WIDTH//2 -1, PATTERN_WIDTH//2 + 1, star_size)

tess = configure_turtle(star_size // 2, SMALL_COLOR)

print_pattern(tess, -PATTERN_WIDTH//2 - 1, PATTERN_WIDTH//2 + 1, star_size, star_size * STAMP_WIDTH//2)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Now you can set `PATTERN_WIDTH` to what you need.  (Try 1 through 10!)  Other changes this time around is that instead of stamping a square and rotating it (which came up slightly short pattern-wise last time), the code defines the shape we need to stamp as a polygon.  The math has changed slightly to accomodate easily changing the pattern width.

**OUTPUT**

[image]